# Implement server-push with GWTP

Tags: gwt, comet, gwt-rpc, gwt-platform

I got a project using GWTP (which involves MVP separation, Gin and Dispatch), now I'm on the situation where it is required that changes on the server are pushed to specific clients

I've reading the gwt-comet and gwteventservice documentation, It seems the first doesn't work with RPC and the second Ecnapsulates RPC, for which I don't know how to fit it in my current command pattern from GWTP. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used "Server Push in GWT" described here http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/ServerPushFAQ - it seemed to work fairly well for a small project.

Answer (score 3):

I have been using gwt-comet (http://code.google.com/p/gwt-comet/). It's a native comet implementation working pretty good like RPC, you can send Strings or your GWT-serialized objects as well. And the best thing you don't need to do many things to make it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a servlet problem, not a GWT or GWTP problem.

So there are a few approaches to doing this, the most stable (in my opinion) is to have a long or blocking poll servlet.  This is basically a servlet that is polled by the client, and holds the connection open for some period of time if there is no message to 'push' to the client, and if too much time passes (this is to get around http timeouts) a heartbeat is returned of some kind.  Either way, when the servlet request request returns, the client just makes another request.  This is the most portable and stable way to my mind, since it uses only the core servlet api, doesn't suffer from network issues, and the blocking portion allows you to have the poll 'park' at the server for some period of time and reduces total request load, while allowing very quick return of new information to the client when there is some available.

The next way to achieve this is via WebSockets, this is great once you get it working and in my opinion is the way of the future without question. I think this is a good one to work with since this will be, in my opinion, a paradigm shift in web applications once it catches a head of steam, so we all need to be up to speed. Basically, you have a javascript 'socket' open via port 80 (this is one of the best features, since you don't have to open any firewall holes) and can communicate in two directions across that socket.

Comet can also work, but it will generally lock you down to one server type, which may be alright for your application.  Caveat here!!!! I have only done very small tests with comet, it was flaky for me when I set it up, and was not as steady as the blocking poll solution *as I had it set up*.

Now the neatest one in my opinion, but this one is very limited due to network constraints probably to single domain intranet applications, is to use an applet based push.  This setup (which could be done with udp or a straight socket, I did all web just to keep it all simpler conceptually) takes the applet, uses it to spin up a jetty server instance on the client, and the has the page publish the client's  jetty 'endpoint' to the server. At this point, the client can contact the server using it's servlets, and the server can contact the client at the servlet(s) exposed on the jetty server. This is true push, it's neato, but there are network nightmares.

So of all the above, I use long polling, keep my eye on web sockets since they are the future in my mind, and really like the applet based version, although it's quite restricted in use due to the network resolution limitations.

Once you have this decided, from GWTP you would just have actions or JSNI bridge methods as needed to connect to your server and receive responses.  I won't go into this, since this is really a core servlet/http/javascript question more than a GWT or GWTP centric question.

I hope that helps!